# update top registries from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table with two primary keys and with many rows.

I'm getting the following message from Sql Server:

> Msg 512, Nível 16, Estado 1, Procedimento TR_GaProTab, Linha 21 [Linha de Início do Lote 2]
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
;WITH query as (
        select top 100 * from GaProTab 
        where EmpCod = '11111111000111' and ProAtv = 1
    )
Update
    query
SET
    ProAtv = 2
```

Comment: 1st Do not use `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`. 2nd the error message is pretty clear, your query returns more than 1 row, and there is a lot of posts about that. That  because you use `TOP 100`

Comment: I understand it, but I can't update the entire table which has more than 900 results. What options do I have?

Comment: Please share a sample data and the expected results as _formatted text_ not images. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found what was going on...
I had two triggers enabled on this table, after I've disabled then, the command runs with success.

Thank you everyone. I'll leave the command bellow:

```
select EmpCod, GaProTab.ProCod into #Tmp
from GaProTab , (select top 100 ProCod from GaProTab where EmpCod ='11111111000111')
AS top100
where GaProTab.ProCod = top100.ProCod
and EmpCod = '11111111000111' and ProAtv = 1

update GaProTab SET ProAtv = 2 
from GaProTab, #Tmp
AS top100
where GaProTab.ProCod = top100.ProCod
and GaProTab.EmpCod = '11111111000111' and ProAtv = 1
```

Comment: Your triggers need some serious help. Seeing temp tables in a trigger will give me nightmares. Also, in your trigger you have top with no order by. Also, you should start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for more than 25 years now.  https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And another red flag, if you have to disable triggers to update your data then something has gone horribly wrong in your trigger.

Comment: It is an old database that i'm using for tests. I'm a beginner in development/sql-server world. I'll read this link that you gave me. I'd really appreciate your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just update the CTE directly as

```
WITH Query AS
(
  SELECT TOP 100 *
  FROM GaProTab
  WHERE EmpCod = '11111111000111'
        AND
        ProAtv = 1
  ORDER BY [WhatEver]
)
UPDATE Query
SET ProAtv = 2;
```

Here is a simple [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e3797857e142e7b048233534253b64e).